# Ajax fetching the index page instead of the value

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to fetch cities from states using ajax in codeigniter 2.1.4. Problem that I am facing is instead of the data its fetching the entire html index page. Unable to solve the problem please help. I code is below:

### Controller

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('home_model');
        $this->load->model('sub_cat_model');
        $this->load->model('state_model');
        $this->load->model('city_model');
        $this->load->model('location_model');
        $this->load->library('email');
    }

    public function index(){
        $data['state'] = $this->home_model->get_state();
        $data['title'] = 'Rimi Classified - Home';

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('index', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }

    public function sign_up(){
        $data['states'] = $this->state_model->get_states();

        $data['error'] = '';
        $data['title'] = 'Rimi Classified - Sign up';
        $this->load->view('templates/header1', $data);
        $this->load->view('sign-up', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }

    public function get_cities($state){
        header('Content-Type: application/x-json; charset=utf-8');
        die(json_encode($this->city_model->get_cities($state)));
    }
}
```

### City Model

```
class City_model extends CI_Model{

    public function __construct(){
        $this -> load -> database();
        //$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
    }

    function get_cities($state){
        if($state != NULL){
            $this->db->where('state_id', $state);

            $query = $this->db->get('city');
            $cities = array();
            if($query->result()){
                foreach($query->result() as $city){
                    $cities[$city->id] = $city->city;
                }
                return $cities;
            }else{
                return FALSE;
            }
        }else{
            $cities[] = "-- Select City --";
            return $cities;
        }
    }
}
```

### State Model

```
class State_model extends CI_Model{

    public function __construct(){
        $this -> load -> database();
    }

    function get_states() {
        $query = $this->db->order_by('state', 'ASC')->get('state');

        $states = array();

        if($query -> result()){
            foreach($query->result() as $state){
                $states[$state -> id] = $state -> state;
            }
            return $states;
        }else{
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

### View

```
<div id="innerdiv1">
    <label>State</label>
    <br />
    <?php
        $states['#'] = '-- Select State --';

        echo form_dropdown('state_id', $states, '#', 'id=state_id');
    ?>
</div>

<div id="innerdiv2">
    <label>City</label>
    <br />
    <div id="city">
        <select name="city_id" id="city_id">
            <option value="">-- Select City-- </option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

### AJAX

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $('#states-dropdown select').change(function (){
            var selState = $(this).attr('value');
            console.log(selState);
            $.ajax({
                url: "pages/get_cities", 
                async: false, 
                type: "POST", 
                data: "state="+selState, 
                dataType: "html",

                success: function(data) {
                    //data is the html of the page where the request is made.
                    $('#city').html(data);
                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: which view call? please try echo instead of die

Comment: Shall I have to do anything in the routes.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the routes.php posted in the comments, change

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/category_list/$1';
```

into

```
$route['pages/category_list/(:any)'] = 'pages/category_list/$1';
```

Note two things are wrong I noticed in the code, but I'm not sure if they are the cause:

1- Do not use "die" call echo or print the data instead, use die for errors only

2- The ajax call should be "GET" not "POST":

```
  $.ajax({   
        url: "pages/get_cities/"+selState,
    async: false,
    type: "GET", 
    success: function(data) {
            //data is the html of the page where the request is made.
    $('#city').html(data);
    },
    error: function(response) {
    //Do Something on Error
    }
     });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but the problem still persist. Problem I am facing is its fetching the entire html index page instead of the dropdown.

Comment: Can you post your routes.php contents please?

Comment: $route['logout'] = 'pages/logout';
$route['sign-up'] = 'pages/sign_up';
$route['change-password'] = 'pages/change_password';
$route['forgot-password'] = 'pages/forgotPassword';
$route['ad-details/(:any)'] = 'pages/ad_details/$1';
$route['login'] = 'pages/login';
$route['ad-list/(:any)'] = 'pages/ad_list/$1';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/category_list/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages';
$route['404_override'] = '';

Comment: If I am changing the url path from url: "pages/get_cities",  to url: "get_cities", its fetching the default controller html else fetching the category_list html page but unable to fetch the city dropdown.

Comment: Change this: $route['(:any)'] = 'pages/category_list/$1'; into $route['pages/category_list/(:any)'] = 'pages/category_list/$1'; or whatere url you want.. maybe "category_list/(:any)" and give it a try

Comment: Sure I am a newbie in codeigniter and stackoverflow have been trying to sort the error for many hours thanks for your help. Also let me know if I can give any review to your profile. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome, just mark this answer as the correct one or give it a vote

Comment: [take a look here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow)

Comment: and to vote just click the up arrow next to the answer

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
var url = "pages/get_cities/" + $(this).attr('value');
 $.ajax({
    url: url,
    async: false,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data) {
        $('#city').html(data);
    }
})
```

php code

```
public function get_cities($state){
    header('Content-Type: application/x-json; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode($this->city_model->get_cities($state));
    return ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but the problem still persist. Problem I am facing is its fetching the entire html index page instead of the dropdown.

Comment: Shall I have to do anything in routes.php?

Comment: try to make blank view for your function and than echo your json on that page